# having trouble with bomb lab phase 4

Tags: assembly, x86, reverse-engineering

I'm having a really hard time understanding what to do here. I thought one of the numbers I would be able to work with was going to be 85 but it seems I am wrong with this. I know I should only get 2 decimals out of it but I just cant seem to do it. Help would be very appreciated.

phase_4

```
Dump of assembler code for function phase_4:
0x08048cd1 <+0>:    push   %ebp
0x08048cd2 <+1>:    mov    %esp,%ebp
0x08048cd4 <+3>:    sub    $0x28,%esp
0x08048cd7 <+6>:    lea    -0xc(%ebp),%eax
0x08048cda <+9>:    mov    %eax,0xc(%esp)
0x08048cde <+13>:   lea    -0x10(%ebp),%eax
0x08048ce1 <+16>:   mov    %eax,0x8(%esp)
0x08048ce5 <+20>:   movl   $0x804a5d7,0x4(%esp)
0x08048ced <+28>:   mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax
0x08048cf0 <+31>:   mov    %eax,(%esp)
0x08048cf3 <+34>:   call   0x8048860 <__isoc99_sscanf@plt>
0x08048cf8 <+39>:   cmp    $0x2,%eax
0x08048cfb <+42>:   jne    0x8048d03 <phase_4+50>
0x08048cfd <+44>:   cmpl   $0xe,-0x10(%ebp)
0x08048d01 <+48>:   jbe    0x8048d08 <phase_4+55>
0x08048d03 <+50>:   call   0x80491d7 <explode_bomb>
0x08048d08 <+55>:   movl   $0xe,0x8(%esp)
0x08048d10 <+63>:   movl   $0x0,0x4(%esp)
0x08048d18 <+71>:   mov    -0x10(%ebp),%eax
0x08048d1b <+74>:   mov    %eax,(%esp)
0x08048d1e <+77>:   call   0x8048c80 <func4>
0x08048d23 <+82>:   test   %eax,%eax
0x08048d25 <+84>:   jne    0x8048d2d <phase_4+92>
0x08048d27 <+86>:   cmpl   $0x0,-0xc(%ebp)
0x08048d2b <+90>:   je     0x8048d32 <phase_4+97>
0x08048d2d <+92>:   call   0x80491d7 <explode_bomb>
0x08048d32 <+97>:   leave  
0x08048d33 <+98>:   ret
```

function 4:

```
Dump of assembler code for function func4:
0x08048c80 <+0>:    push   %ebp
0x08048c81 <+1>:    mov    %esp,%ebp
0x08048c83 <+3>:    sub    $0x18,%esp
0x08048c86 <+6>:    mov    0x8(%ebp),%edx
0x08048c89 <+9>:    mov    0xc(%ebp),%eax
0x08048c8c <+12>:   mov    0x10(%ebp),%ecx
0x08048c8f <+15>:   sub    %eax,%ecx
0x08048c91 <+17>:   shr    %ecx
0x08048c93 <+19>:   add    %eax,%ecx
0x08048c95 <+21>:   cmp    %edx,%ecx
0x08048c97 <+23>:   jbe    0x8048cae <func4+46>
0x08048c99 <+25>:   dec    %ecx
0x08048c9a <+26>:   mov    %ecx,0x8(%esp)
0x08048c9e <+30>:   mov    %eax,0x4(%esp)
0x08048ca2 <+34>:   mov    %edx,(%esp)
0x08048ca5 <+37>:   call   0x8048c80 <func4>
0x08048caa <+42>:   add    %eax,%eax
0x08048cac <+44>:   jmp    0x8048ccf <func4+79>
0x08048cae <+46>:   mov    $0x0,%eax
0x08048cb3 <+51>:   cmp    %edx,%ecx
0x08048cb5 <+53>:   jae    0x8048ccf <func4+79>
0x08048cb7 <+55>:   mov    0x10(%ebp),%eax
0x08048cba <+58>:   mov    %eax,0x8(%esp)
0x08048cbe <+62>:   inc    %ecx
0x08048cbf <+63>:   mov    %ecx,0x4(%esp)
0x08048cc3 <+67>:   mov    %edx,(%esp)
0x08048cc6 <+70>:   call   0x8048c80 <func4>
0x08048ccb <+75>:   lea    0x1(%eax,%eax,1),%eax
0x08048ccf <+79>:   leave  
0x08048cd0 <+80>:   ret
```

Comment: Slight variation of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19640148/binary-bomb-phase-4/19646901). If that's enough help, I'll close as duplicate.

Comment: Yeah that one has been the most helpful so far but I am having a hard time finding where I would get my initial value to start working with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously the second number has to be zero, since that's what the code checks at `0x08048d27`.

The first number has to be chosen such that the return value of `func4` is also zero (see `0x08048d23`). If you look into `func4` you can see that it is a binary search ([explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19646901/547981) of a similar code here). When the item is found, it returns zero. Otherwise if it falls into the lower half, it returns `2*func4()`. Finally if it is in the higher half, it returns `2*func4()+1`.

Given that in this case the result has to be zero, that means the number has to be found while only traversing the lower ranges, since otherwise a `+1` would creep into the result. Zero itself is a trivial solution since that will certainly be found at the bottom.

For sake of completeness, here is a walkthrough for the other possibilities. The first guess will be the midpoint in the range `[0, 14]`, which is `7`. For the next step, we know the number must be less than `7` to get range `[0, 6]` and that means midpoint `3`. Similarly, the next range is `[0, 2]` with midpoint `1`. Finally we arrive at `[0, 0]`, the trivial result.

TL;DR: The possible inputs are `0 0`, `1 0`, `3 0` and `7 0`.

---

Since there are versions of this with other expected results, here is some additional help: The return value actually spells out the low-high choices in binary, starting from the least significant bit. In the above example, we had all `0` bits, so all low choices. Suppose we have a result of `4` that is `100` in binary. Reading from the right, that means we need a lower, another lower and a final upper recursion. Following through the ranges, those map to `[0, 6]`, `[0, 2]` and `[2, 2]`. So in this case `2` would be the solution.

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much I had an incredibly frustrating time with this one, the answer was 0 0.

Comment: @GunR The other 3 should work just as fine.